# How to change goldendict system tray icon?

Tags: unity, icons, dictionary

I'm trying to change goldendict system tray icon, and can't find one in system files. I managed however to change launcher icon: it's located in `/usr/share/pixmaps/Dictionary-icon.png`, but system tray icon stayed the same. Any suggestions on where to find that one?
I'm using ubuntu 12.04 LTS with default unity desktop and goldendict version 1.0.1.

Comment: [Here's an icon set I just created myself](http://askubuntu.com/questions/193777/how-can-i-convert-a-coloured-icon-to-a-monochrome-one/193805#193805). Thought you might be interest in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tray icon is compiled-in, you'll have to recompile Goldendict to change the tray icon. http://goldendict.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=807

Comment: Thanks. It's all clear now. I thought I was missing something.